# Autofac Dependency Injection - resolve to different type based on the assembly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm building a c# Asp.Net application.
I have three assemblies in my project.

- MainAssembly
- AssemblyA
- AssemblyB

`AssemblyA` and `AssemblyB` has reference to MainAssembly. MainAssembly will load `AssemblyA` and `AssemblyB`using Reflection.
There is a need AutoFac to resolve the type based on the assembly where it resides.

In other words constructor parameters should be resolved to `SmsSender`, or `EmailSender` based on in which assembly it belongs to.

Consider below code:

--------------------------**Code inside MainAssembly**--------------------------

```
//Global Registration
void AutofacRegister()
{
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
   ...
   ...
   //Registering the modules in other assemblies
   builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(AssemblyA);
   builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(AssemblyB);
   ...

}

interface ISender
{
  void SendMessage();
}
```

--------------------------**Code inside AssemblyB**----------------------------

```
public class ComponentA: Module
{
   protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
   {
       builder.RegisterType<SmsSender>().As<ISender>();
   }
}

internal class SmsSender : ISender{...}

public class Foo()
{
   Foo(ISender sender)
   {
      //as this is inside a AssemblyA thi should be resolved to type SmsSender
      //SmsSender
   }
}
```

--------------------------**Code inside AssemblyB**----------------------------

```
public class ComponentA: Module
{
   protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
   {
       builder.RegisterType<EmailSender>().As<ISender>();
   }
}

internal class EmailSender : ISender{...}

public class Bar()
{
   Bar(ISender sender)
   {
      //as this is inside a AssemblyB this should be resolved to type EmailSender
      //EmailSender
   }
}
```

How can I achieve the requirement? 
Could any one help me by providing an simple example?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to solve your issue, but you have to explicitly "tell" your `Foo` and `Bar` classes which `ISender` they should use. You could use "named instances" to do so.

First of all, I assume `ISender` interface is not present in MainAssembly, because it would not be accessable in ComponentA and ComponentB, if MainAssembly has references to both these components.

Your **ComponentA** module definition should look like the following:

```
public class ModuleDefinition : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        const string emailSender = "EmailSender";

        builder.RegisterType<EmailSender>().As<ISender>().Named<ISender>(emailSender);
        builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
            .WithParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "sender", (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ISender>(emailSender));
    }
}
```

Analogically, **ComponentB** module definition would look like this:

```
public class ModuleDefinition : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        const string smsSender = "SmsSender";

        builder.RegisterType<SmsSender>().As<ISender>().Named<ISender>(smsSender);
        builder.RegisterType<Bar>()
            .WithParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "sender", (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ISender>(smsSender));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I explicitly configure which `ISender` implementation should be used by both `Foo` and `Bar` classes, using `.WithParameter` configuration method.

AFAIK there is no implicit "based on assembly" way of doing this.

Comment: I have specified wrong relationship between the assemblies. Now I have updated the question. Sorry About It. Is your answer still valid? Should i have to do any changes?

Comment: Yes, the answer is still valid when `ISender` is in MainAssembly, and AssemblyA and AssemblyB have reference to MainAssembly

Comment: What if Foo & Bar classes are derived from a base class, and if i need to resolve the base class type with Autofac? According to your answer somethink like this:  `builder.RegisterType<BaseClass>()
            .WithParameter((p, c)...`